# Decode json using javascript web

Tags: javascript, json, decode

When I run this code/try to decode this

```
var data = JSON.parse({"forms":[{"url":"example.com/example","name":"example"}]})
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=data.forms.name
```

the value returned **undefined**.

So what is the proper way to decode it using web javascript?

Comment: That is because `data.forms` contains an array, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the object itself?

```
var data = {"forms": [{"url":"example.com/example","name":"example"}]};
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=data.forms[0].name
```

`JSON.parse()` is taking string as a parameter. You don't need to parse it, because you already have the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are providing a JSON object, yuo don't have to parse it.

```
const data = JSON.parse('{"forms":[{"url":"example.com/example","name":"example"}]}')
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=data.forms[0].name
```

And the 'form.data' field is an array. you should access it before reading any property.